# Parent child hierarchy with order by on name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, parent-child

I want to create SQL Server query for the following. I have data like:

```
Id       Name       parentId
1         STU        0
2         XYZ        5
3         PQR        5
4         EFG        0
5         ABC        0
6         HIJ        1
7         DEF        1
```

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parentId = 0 THEN id ELSE parentId END ASC, id ASC
```

Output (parent and its children are sorted together):

```
Id       Name       parentId
1         STU        0
6         HIJ        1
7         DEF        1
4         EFG        0
5         ABC        0
2         XYZ        5
3         PQR        5
```

Now I am required to sort by name as well, first by parent's name and then all children, also sorted by name. The expected output is:

```
Id       Name       parentId
5         ABC        0
3         PQR        5
2         XYZ        5
4         EFG        0
1         STU        0
7         DEF        1
6         HIJ        1
```

Does anyone have solution for this? I need strict SQL Server query for this.

**P.S. There is going to have only one level of hierarchy.**

Comment: Could a Child also have a child? If so, do you need to catter for that as well?

Comment: What if you had multiple levels? should the result be sorted by hierarchy and then by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward, really:

```
SELECT
    category.*,
    -- bring parent and its children together
    CASE WHEN parent.Id IS NULL THEN category.Name ELSE parent.Name END AS sort1,
    -- move parent to top followed by its children
    CASE WHEN parent.Id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE category.Name END AS sort2
FROM category
LEFT JOIN category AS parent ON category.parentId = parent.Id
ORDER BY sort1, sort2
```

Output:

```
+------+------+----------+-------+-------+
| Id   | Name | parentId | sort1 | sort2 |
+------+------+----------+-------+-------+
|    5 | ABC  |        0 | ABC   | NULL  |
|    3 | PQR  |        5 | ABC   | PQR   |
|    2 | XYZ  |        5 | ABC   | XYZ   |
|    4 | EFG  |        0 | EFG   | NULL  |
|    1 | STU  |        0 | STU   | NULL  |
|    7 | DEF  |        1 | STU   | DEF   |
|    6 | HIJ  |        1 | STU   | HIJ   |
+------+------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Note that I have placed the sort calculations inside the `SELECT` clause in order to explain how it works.

Comment: This will fail with multi level hierarchy.

Comment: Its going to have only one level hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you salman. I am going to use this solution as this has no advanced feature needed + requirement is for 1 level parent-child hierarchy so its best solution for me as of now.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every hierarchy question in SQL Server is solved with a recursive cte.
You didn't mention if there can be more than one level of hierarchy, but since there is no way to prevent that other then writing an instead of trigger or a udf based check constraint, I am going on the assumption that there can be multi-level hierarchy rows.
The trick to this answer is the fact that sorting numbers alphabetically is different than sorting them numerically.
If you sorted `1, 11, 2, 13, 21, 3` in a **numeric** sort,
you will get `1, 2, 3, 11, 13, 21`.
However, sorting the same numbers in **alphabetical** sort,
you will get `1, 11, 13, 2, 21, 3`.

Now, enough talk, let's see some code!
First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int,
    [Name] char(3),
    parentId int
)
INSERT INTO @T (Id, [Name], parentId) VALUES
(1, 'STU', 0),
(2, 'XYZ', 5),
(3, 'PQR', 5),
(4, 'EFG', 0),
(5, 'ABC', 0),
(6, 'HIJ', 1),
(7, 'DEF', 1),
(8, 'AAA', 3),
(9, 'ZZZ', 3)
```

**Note**: I've added two more rows for grandchildren to check multi-level hierarchy.

The cte:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id, 
            [Name], 
            ParentId, 
            -- Row_Number returns a bigint - max value have 19 digits
            CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Name]) as varchar(19)) As Sort
    FROM @T 
    WHERE parentId = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  T.Id, 
            T.[Name], 
            T.ParentId,
            CAST(Sort + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.[Name]) as varchar(19)) as varchar(19))
    FROM @T T
    JOIN CTE ON T.parentId = CTE.Id 
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT Id, [Name], ParentId
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Sort -- alphabetic sort will order 11 before 2...
```

Results:

```
Id  Name    ParentId
5   ABC     0
3   PQR     5
8   AAA     3
9   ZZZ     3
2   XYZ     5
4   EFG     0
1   STU     0
7   DEF     1
6   HIJ     1
```

Comment: Glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT
  RN =0,   
  ID,
      NAME,
     parentId = ID
  FROM T1
    WHERE parentId = 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.parentId ORDER BY T1.name asc),
     T1.ID,
      T1.NAME,
  T1.parentId
  FROM T1
   INNER JOIN T1 T2
      ON T1.parentId =T2.ID

)
SELECT
id,
name,
parentid
FROM CTE
ORDER BY parentId DESC,RN
```

Comment: `Row_number()`  returns `bigint` so you need to cast to `bigint` on your anchor part of the cte. also, this returns the wrong parent id for top level rows, and it will fail if there is more than one level of hierarchy.

Comment: I've tested it and works fine without casting as bigint and returns the rows as expected. but I agree that this will not work for records with more than 1 level

Comment: Perhaps it's a version issue. I've tested on 2016 and I got an error.

Comment: I'm using 2014.

Comment: Thank you Jayasurya

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this with dynamic Sql if you don't know the child depth. But since you only seem to have a depthLevel of 2 a simple version of that  this might work:

```
declare @tempT table(ID int, name varchar(3), parentID int, sortLevel1 int, sortlevel2 int)

insert into @tempT
select t1.ID,t1.name,t1.parentID,RowNumber() Over(order by (select null)),-1
from table t1  
where parentId=0
order by t1.name 

insert into @tempT
select t2.ID,t2.name,t2.parentID,t1.sortLevel1,RowNumber() Over(order by (select null))
from table t1  
join @tempT t2 on t1.id=t2.parentID
order by t2.name

select * from @temp order by t1.sortLevel1, sortLevel2
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I've found that `Zohar Peled`'s solution fails if one of the hierarchy levels have >9 entries. I solved it by modifying his code where he constructs a "Sort" column by adding leading zeros.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id, 
            [Name], 
            ParentId, 
            -- Row_Number returns a bigint - max value have 19 digits
            CAST(FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Name]), 'D4') as varchar(12)) As Sort
    FROM @T 
    WHERE parentId = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  T.Id, 
            T.[Name], 
            T.ParentId,
            CAST(Sort + CAST(FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Name]), 'D4') as varchar(4)) as varchar(12))
    FROM @T T
    JOIN CTE ON T.parentId = CTE.Id 
)
```

In my case I didn't need more than 4 characters. But if you need more just add by yourself and don't forget to change the length of Sort column according to the number of levels you have in a hierarchy multiplied by the length of characters you need.